# Final value of a global variable which is being incremented via two threads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, race-condition

I encountered this question:

> Given two threads and one global variable `var`, the two threads runs
>   the same code (C/C++ code):
>
> ```
> for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
> {
>   var++;
> }
> ```
>
> What are the possible values of `var` at the end of the threads
>   execution?

If each thread increments `var` "correctly" - I guess that the maximum value will be 40.

But what about the minimum value? How is the increment operation implemented and actually being done?

Note: There is no locking (of any type) on the increment operation on purpose (off course that the correct way would be to lock it - the question is for educational purposes).

Comment: I guess the question is if `var++` is atomic, i.e. the write and the read of the variable can't be interrupted by another thread. If it can be interrupted, then both threads might read the same value of `var` and both increment it at the same time, thus var will not be 40 in the end

Comment: @hansaplast - As far as I know, you can never assume that the increment operation is atomic. Also, the two threads might run on two different cores so I think "cache coherency" issues should be considered here (might effect) the final value of var at the end of the program.

Comment: The behaviour is undefined. One possible final value for `var` is a bowl of petunias.

Comment: Speculating on the behaviour of acknowledged bad code is pointless and of no use to future SO users/visitors.

Comment: _I encountered this question:_ aka my homework is

Comment: @n.m. Oh no, not again.  ;)

Comment: There is no synchronization between the threads, so the code produces a **data race**. As a result, the behavior **of the program** is undefined. That means that running **the program** can do anything and still conform to the language definition.

Answer (score 7):

If `var` is **not** an atomic type then the behaviour is *undefined*. Questions about the *range* of possible final values are therefore ill-posed.

If `var` is an atomic type, then the final result will be as if the threads were not ran concurrently.

Comment: I don't understand. C is compiling down the loop to read, increment and write operations. If single-threaded the outcome is deterministic, if multi-threaded then you have two lines of read, increment and write, the question then is how you aline the two lines, and that has a set of possible outcomes, so it is not fully undefined, no?

Comment: @hansaplast: You can't reason about undefined behaviour like that. Informally speaking, you have a race condition, and that's broadly speaking undefined behaviour in C and C++.

Comment: my beliefs are shattered :) Judging from your C/C++ points on SO I believe you are right. Can you point me to any article/resource on why this kind of reasoning is wrong?

Comment: @hansaplast: Yes it's a bit like discovering the truth about Father Christmas. Here's a starting link. https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong

Answer (score 3):

If you don't do any locking, then `var++` is not atomic  i.e. the write and the read of the variable can be interrupted by another thread. That means both threads might read the same value of var and both increment it at the same time.

Worst case the two threads are fully "synchronized" that is read and write the var at exactly same time and thus the minimal end value of `var` would be 20.

**Update**: Apparently, there are no guarantees about possible outcomes in these data races, see Bathsheba answer below and [this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) he refers to.

**Update 2**: I was curious if in real world we would see values below 20. Test setup (details: see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/98600abe00030e3e6e5791ce1b50f583))

- global `int var`. Tested with `long` and `long long`, didn't do any difference
- two `pthread`s doing 20'000 times `var++`
- executable was started 10'000 times and smallest values was taken

The expected outcome would be between 20'000 and 40'000:

```
|                    Computer                   | clang | clang -O3 |  gcc  | gcc -O0 | gcc -O2 |
|-----------------------------------------------|-------|-----------|-------|---------|---------|
| Linux, ThinkPad, x86_64, Intel I7, 4 cores    | 19402 |     20000 | 18760 |   16913 |   20000 |
| Linux, Raspberry 3, ARMv7, 4 cores            | 19587 |     20000 | 19569 |   19904 |   20000 |
| OSX,  Intel i5, 4 cores                       | 17609 |     20000 | 17206 |   18049 |   20000 |
| Linux, EC2 t2.2xlarge, Intel Xeon E5, 8 cores | 19707 |     20000 | 19744 |   19881 |   40000 |
```

What seems interesting:

- yes, it **can** drop below 20'000, so the "no guarantees" claim is not just in theory
- with compiler optimizations above a certain level the behaviour looks more predictable
- strange, that on EC2 with 8 cores the min value for `gcc -O2` was 40'000.

Comment: In C and C++ the code has a race condition, and it is therefore undefined behavior. With that in mind, it is not meaningful to give guarantees such as a minimum or maximum value, since any guarantees are forfeited when you encounter undefined behavior.

Comment: @nos Hmm.. can you come up with any race condition that would push the minimal end value below 20?

Comment: @hansaplast it is also possible for the value to turn out to be negative, since the semantics of race conditions aren't defined in C.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - How is it possible (negative value or even below 20 of var at the end of the program)?

Comment: @GuyAvraham because race condition is undefined behavior and anything can happen. But to give you a case where it __can__ happen, `int` is a multibyte data type in memory. On some platform and some representation of integers, it could lead to interleaved partial writes which can lead to a negative value.

Comment: @hansaplast The compiler could analyze the program and determine that the global variable is not used and just eliminate the loop and assignment to the global variable (the compiler could make that assumption even if the there are code that actually uses the variable, as the compiler can also assume that no undefined behavior occurs). Some compilers have options that would halt or crash the program when it detects a race condition, in which case there would also be no value assigned to the global variable.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya *On some platform and some representation of integers, it could lead to interleaved partial writes which can lead to a negative value* Even x86 probably isn't immune to that, if the `int` value is misaligned in memory.

Comment: @nos I ran some tests on different environments and: indeed one can really not add guarantees. Any thoughts on the outcome?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: ping, I did some tests maybe you want to comment?